# How to select from Solr in Java code?

Tags: java, solr

I save data in Solr:

```
String solrUrl = "http://localhost:8984/solr";
SolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer( solrUrl );
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField("id", "1");
doc.addField("first_name", "Ann");
doc.addField("last_name", "Smit");
doc.addField("email", "test@test.com");
try {
   solrServer.add(doc);
   solrServer.commit();
} catch (SolrServerException e) {/* */}
```

And I want to search in solr:

```
SolrQuery parameters = new SolrQuery();
parameters.setQuery("*:*");
parameters.setParam("first_name", "Ann");
QueryResponse response = null;
try {
   response = solrServer.query(parameters);
} catch (SolrServerException e) {/* */ }
SolrDocumentList list = response.getResults();
```

And I have 1 records - it's good. But when I set `parameters.setParam("first_name", "Ann1");` I have the same result. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`parameters.setQuery("*:*");` will add `q=*:*` to url, and this query matches all documents in solr(because its * wildcard char in both field:value).

`parameters.setParam("first_name", "Ann");` has no effect because this will add `first_name=Ann` query param to url. (Note that your filters should go as value to `q` or `fq` query param and not directly as separate query param!)
So, the final query will be `q=*:*&first_name=Ann` which in lucene's language is to query for all docs.

If you are trying to match only the documents with `first_name==Ann` then you need try `?q=first_name:Ann`

```
SolrQuery parameters = new SolrQuery();
parameters.setQuery("first_name:Ann");
```

Answer (score 1):

Search works based on your query in **setQuery("*:*");**

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("*:*");
query.setFields("id","first_name","last_name");
query.setStart(0);
query.setRows(100);
QueryResponse response = server.query(query);
SolrDocumentList docResults = response.getResults();
```

Your query should be in setQuery method and setFields() will make search on specified fields only.

Your are searching *:* so it return all documents. setParam("first_name","Ann") has no effect. Change your code like below.

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("first_name:Ann1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Should use:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("*:*");
query.addFilterQuery("first_name:qwe*", "last_name:qwe*");
query.setFields("id","first_name","last_name","email");
QueryResponse response = null;
try {
    response = solrServer.query(query);
} catch (SolrServerException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
SolrDocumentList list = response.getResults();
```