# How to select from solr use java?

Tags: java, solr

I save data in solr:

```
String solrUrl = "http://localhost:8984/solr";
SolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer( solrUrl );
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField("id", "1");
doc.addField("first_name", "Ann");
doc.addField("last_name", "Smit");
doc.addField("email", "test@test.com");
try {
   solrServer.add(doc);
   solrServer.commit();
} catch (SolrServerException e) {/* */}
```

And select data from solr:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("*:*");
query.addFilterQuery("first_name:Ann*");
query.addFilterQuery("last_name:Ann*");
query.setFields("id","first_name","last_name","email");
QueryResponse response = null;
try {
    response = solrServer.query(query);
} catch (SolrServerException e) {/* */ }
SolrDocumentList list = response.getResults();
```

I have search criteria: first name **or** last name should contain value `Ann`. How to set `FilterQuery` for select saved data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011413/how-to-select-from-solr-in-java-code/27013728#27013728

Answer (score 1):

Should use:

```
SolrQuery parameters = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("first_name:qwe2 OR last_name:qwe2");
query.setFields("id","first_name","last_name","email");
QueryResponse response = null;
try {
    response = solrServer.query(parameters);
} catch (SolrServerException e) {/* */ }
SolrDocumentList list = response.getResults();
```

Answer (score 0):

Search using SolrJ

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
public class SolrJSearcher {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, SolrServerException {
    HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("url");

    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setQuery("sony digital camera");
    query.addFilterQuery("cat:electronics","store:amazon.com");
    query.setFields("id","price","merchant","cat","store");
    query.setStart(0);    
    query.set("defType", "edismax");

    QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);
    SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
      System.out.println(results.get(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see this example yet. What should change in my code?